# Which is a more preferable Geometry in Objective C Programming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graphics

It took me up to this point that I still do not understand what is the difference and which is better to use for geometrical programming in Objective C. I understand that NextStep has its own version of C Geometry (Quartz) but what is much more preferable to study and appropriate for iPhone dev?

Comment: What are you trying to draw? You say geometry, which leads me to think OpenGL, but that might be overkill for just drawing squares or circles in 2D. Can you describe what you're trying to draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's CoreGraphics, if you just want to draw on a UIView. You could look at higher level options such as Core Plot: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

An alternative is to place a UIWebView in your app and use one of a myriad of JavaScript libraries and/or SVG.

Comment: is CoreGraphics better than Cocoa's Quartz?